# How can I send a confirmation email to users of my application?

Tags: java, email

I have designed a chat application where different users can create the account, but I do not know how to send a confirmation email to the users. Since I collect their e-mail address in the registration form, how can I send mail to those addresses in Java?

Comment: @giri: you could check out how some Open Source Java project does actually send an email.  *JForum* for example is written in Java and does send confirmation/verification email: http://jforum.net (this is not really answer, hence I made it a comment ; )

Comment: @Wiz: regardless, you still need a SMTP server. If I am not mistaken, they also makes use of JavaMail API.

Comment: @BalusC: oh definitely... That's why I made it a comment and not an answer (btw you hadn't answered yet when I posted the comment): I'm pretty sure they're using JavaMail and a "typical" install uses a GMail account and use Google's SMTP server, that way you don't need to set up and maintain your own mail server (with all the problem of RBL/whitelisting/etc. this entails).  It was some kind of *"Use the source, Luke!"* comment, not an actual answer : )   <-- Java developer but JForum *user* here : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need a [SMTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). It's required to be able to send emails. You can make use of the SMTP server associated with your own existing email account, such as the one from your ISP or public mailboxes like Gmail, Yahoo, etc. You can find SMTP connection details at their documentation. You usually just need to know the hostname and the port number. The login details are just the same as from your email account.

You're however restricted to using your own address in the `From` field of the email and usually also in the amount of emails you're allowed to send at certain intervals. If you'd like to get around this, then you need to install your own SMTP server, for example [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/), which is Java based, or Microsoft Exchange and so on.

Then, to send an email using Java code, you would need the [JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) or the more convenienced [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good site for you: http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=javamail.sql&id=18274

Google 'send mail java'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this really depends on the environment that your JVM is running in.

If you're running in a standard Linux/UNIX environment and don't want to faff about with extra libraries, then one way is just to "manually" call sendmail (e.g. via ProcessBuilder). As with executing commands generally, you just need to be slightly careful that you don't just pass user input as parameters without screening them.

Comment: The main intent of Java is to be platformindependent. That's why under each JavaMail exist :)

Comment: Yes, if you actually *need* that platform independency and it's appropriate to expect it in the case in question. If it's your server-side code, then whatever language you program in, in reality it will be coded for your particular server environment in all sorts of places.